# Using loop to create dynamic ImageViews and GestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-development

Can someone explain why this code is not working as expected?
As you can see, I'm using loop to create imageViews with gestureRecognizers.
I don't understand why only the first imageView's gestureRecognizer is working. I hope someone can help.
Thank you!

[image]

```
for (int i = 0; i < tenderList.count; i++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    imageView.tag = 100 + i;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[tenderList objectAtIndex:i].imageUrl]];
    [imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *click = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tenderSelected:)];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:click];

    UIView *row = [rowArray objectAtIndex:i];
    [row addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make)
     {
         make.left.equalTo(@20);
         make.right.equalTo(@-20);

         make.centerY.equalTo(row);

         make.height.equalTo(row).multipliedBy(0.8);
     }];
}
```

Comment: may be your other imageviews overlapped by some views! make sure that!

Comment: @Nathaniel - can you post a screenshot of your views? Lion is correct, check the hierarchies.  Your code should work since you're already setting userInteraction to YES.

Comment: What is *"not working as expected"*? Are you not seeing images? Are you seeing images, but they are not where you want them to be? Are you seeing images, but tapping doesn't do anything? Is the tapping calling a handler, but not giving you the results you want at that point?

Comment: @DonMag The imageViews were displayed properly, it's just, only the first imageView is firing the event, the 2nd up to last imageViews don't trigger the event when tapped. I will post the screenshot

Comment: In the Screenshot you show, it looks like you have only ONE `imageView`? The row that has gray on each side (indicating the imageView has 20-pts on left and right)?

Comment: I can't seem to find how you're adding your each `row` view. You can use Xcode's view debugger to check out your views' hierarchies. You can also add a temporary backgroundColor to your views.

Comment: @Glenn and Donmag
 
The first row and imageView is the Paypal Visa Mastercard.

The second row and imageView is the paydollar alipay unionpay.

These two rows both have gray background, i put them for debugging purposes. It's just the pictures that are not in correct ratio.

In this case, only the first row and imageview (PayPal) is firing the event.

Comment: @NathanielBrionSison - when your app is running, if you go into Debug View Hierarchy and select each image view, then check the Description at the bottom of the Object Inspector pane... do you see `gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: ...`  listed for each one? or only for the first one?

Comment: @DonMag Here's the description of the two imageviews. They both have gestureRecognizer. I tried to have breakpoint before the adding imageView to row's subView, each imageView has its gestureRecognizer.

Printing description of $4:
<UIImageView: 0x7c61dcb0; frame = (20 5; 280 40); opaque = NO; tag = 100; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c6dc420>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c657cc0>>

Printing description of $5:
<UIImageView: 0x7c6f2960; frame = (20 5; 280 40); opaque = NO; tag = 101; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7c6f0bb0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c6575d0>>

Comment: Things *look* like they should be working. Do you have something like `NSLog(@"got the tap");` in your `tenderSelected` method to confirm the tap is not being triggered?

Comment: Or add a breakpoint inside that method. And if you're just following a tutorial  (means this is not a production level project), and you can link to your question the project source. Just an option if you can't solve the problem by yourself or if this question gets buried. One last thing, 20x20 size of a view is just small to make it tappable.

Comment: @DonMag yes, the NSLog codes are only getting fired by the first element :/

Comment: @Glenn the left: 20 and right: -20 refers to its constraint. that's why there's a space both left and right before the gray background of each imageView

Comment: oh yes, didn't notice it last night. The problem you're having is pretty simple debug if only we're talking in person, or if we have the project. Comment is getting longer, we can start a chat on this thread if needed or post a project repo link if it's merely a tutorial project and I'll be happy to check it out.

Comment: I agree with Glenn -- we need more info, or we need the actual code to help debug it. @NathanielBrionSison, if you can't share your current project, try to create a minimal example that demonstrates the problem (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Chat would be much easier than these comments... unfortunately, you need rep of 20 to use StackOverflow chat.